# PHP how to implement the Data Mapper pattern in MVC

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, datamapper

I'm trying to implement and get my grasp on the Data Mapper pattern in my MVC project. I know this has been asked before, but I'm still not sure if I'm moving in the right direction. I've pasted my Controller, Datamapper and Domain Object/Entity code right below:

## Controller

The user lands on mywebsite.com/dashboard/index and gets to see a list of events from the event log database table. The index() function creates an Datamapper instance and passes a the database wrapper. Then an HTML table is dynamically generated with data fetched from the Data mapper.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController { 
    public function index() {
        require_once '../app/domain/mappers/EventMapper.php';
        require_once '../app/include/HTMLTableCreator.php';

        try {
            $eventMapper = new EventMapper(new Database('db'));
            $table = new HTMLTableCreator($eventMapper->findByLimit(20));
        } catch (DatabaseException $e) {

        }

        $this->view('/home/dashboard', ['table' => $table->toString()]);
    }   
}
```

## Datamapper

This class contains the findByLimit() method for retrieving the last 20 log events from the database. The fetchCollection() method populates the Domain Entities and collects these in an array to be returned to the controller.

Should I create a generic collection function to be used by multiple Data mappers when the SQL query returns multiple rows (= multiple domain objects)? And can a Data mapper use any type of Data Source?

```
require_once '../app/domain/entities/Event.php';
require_once '../app/domain/interfaces/EventMapperInterface.php';

/**
 * EventMapper class
 */
class EventMapper implements EventMapperInterface {

    protected $dbh;
    protected $elements;

    public function __construct(Database $dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function fetchCollection($objects) {
        foreach($objects as $object) {
            $event = new Event();
            $event->setId($object['id']);
            $event->setDateTime($object['datetime']);
            $event->setMessage($object['message']);
            $event->setHostname($object['hostname']);

            $this->elements[] = $event;
        }

        return $this->elements;
    }

    public function findByLimit($limit = 20) {
        $events = $this->dbh->sql_select('SELECT * FROM eventlog LIMIT ' . $limit, []);

        return $this->fetchCollection($events);
    }   
}
```

## Domain Object/Entity

At last the domain object with some simple getters and setters. Would this be the place to do validation on the properties of a Domain Object?

```
class Event {

    protected $id;
    protected $dateTime;
    protected $message;
    protected $hostname;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setDateTime($dateTime) {
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    }

    public function getDateTime() {
        return $this->dateTime;
    }  

    // rest omitted for clarity
}
```

Am I missing something in my implementation?

Comment: The spec is not known. Hard to say what you are missing. I would look at some existing ORM implementations instead of rolling my own :)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин I disagree .. most ORM Implementations have become an overkill, too many people want to many different things. ORM can't do all of them equally good, only a few things ..

Comment: Yeah, I don't need a complex ORM implementation. By learning from other frameworks/implementations and writing a bit of my own I learn the the most.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a generic collection function to be used by multiple Data mappers when the SQL query returns multiple rows (= multiple domain objects)?

No. If your obects have properties which are 1=1 with db table columns, then use an existing approach; e.g. PDO-FETCH-CLASS. At any rate, it is cleaner to have one mapper per entity. If they are very generic, then use the "super" mapper.

> And can a Data mapper use any type of Data Source?

Assuming that `DataSource` is some kind of collection-read-write interface, then surely. You have `__construct(Database $dbh)`, that can be replaced by `__construct(DataSource $ds)`.

Other notes: Try to inject the database and the mapper service into the controller.

Comment: I'm using mysqli instead of PDO, but I should perhaps look into it. And I would be using the constructor of the controller to inject the database and mapper service right? Then I must assume that all action methods within that controller need that mapper, which applies to the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Would you suggest looking at existing IoC containers? I've been looking around and found several implementations. I'm not sure where I would initialise such a container, but that's another question I think.